# Revisar si POST es igual que la variable de urls/miarchivo.php

Tags: php

Me gustaría hacer lo siguiente:

1. El usuario ingresa un POST | Listo
2. PHP lo valida | Listo
3. Revisar si el POST es igual que la variable `$password` de un archivo `urls/miarchivo.php`.

En miarchivo.php tengo:

```
$password = "contraseñacorrecta";
```

Debe revisar si lo que está dentro de ""; es igual que el POST o regresar un mensaje de error.

Gracias.

Comment: Brother, bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo visitar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que entiendas de qué va el sitio, cómo funciona y qué esperamos de los usuarios, de la misma manera percibo que recién estás comenzando con PHP por lo que aquí tienes: la documentacion oficial de PHP: http://php.net/manual/es/index.php y un par de tutoriales: http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/phpya/ y  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/index.htm Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

A ver si entiendo bien:

Tienes un FORM que manda un dato por POST ...y tu quieres que ese FORM empate el input de contraseña con una variable de un archivo PHP.

Si es así como te entiendo es sencillo:

Haz un include de tu archivo `urls/miarchivo.php`, de ahí la variable $password que se encuentra en `miarchivo.php` ya es accesible, en caso de que haya algún problema a lo más le puedes incluir que se vuelva global (`global $password`) y listo es comparable.

Vamos a verlo en código (recuerda, este código es sencillo no debes usarlo así por seguridad y demás):

```
<?php
     include("urls/miarchivo.php"); //se incluye el archivo donde se encuentra la variable $password
     $passwordDelForm = $_POST['password']; //esta es la contraseña que manda el form

     if($passwordDelForm != ""){ //se checa que no esté vacía
           if($passwordDelForm == $password){ //si empatan las variables
                echo "Contraseña correcta";
           }else{ //si no empatan
                echo "Error en la contraseña";
           }
      }else{ //si está vacía le mostramos un error
           echo "Error en la contraseña";
      }
?>
```

Puedes corroborar después del include por pruebas imprimiendo la variable a ver si te carga y no tiene problemas de accesibilidad, en caso de que así sea solo como mencio

```
<?php
    global $password = "holamundo";
?>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos y suerte.